# How to show https on all pages of site?

Tags: url, url-rewrite, https

I want to show https in my url of all pages of site. Please help me out to make this thing possible. Right now https is only appearing in my home page and checkout page. My site url is https://www.nutriment.com/.

Thanks

Comment: generally https url only on home and checkout page.

Comment: Change you base unsecure url to https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to update your Base Unsecure Url to https:// in `Admin -> System -> Config -> General -> Web` see image below

[image]