# SEO implications of changing to HTTPS

Tags: seo, ssl, https

We plan to install SSL certificate in Magento store and I was wondering if there are any SEO implications to take into consideration? We mean to use the HTTPS on all pages of the site.

Does Magento automatically 301 redirect the non-secured url's to secured ones or do we need to make some server side redirection of all pages?

EDIT:

Also please note that this question is not about how to set the https in use in Magento, but how to make the change as safely as possible considering SEO.

EDIT 2:

I added this to my .htaccess file to make sure that all HTTP pages are 301 redirected to the HTTPS version of the same pages:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show https on all pages of site?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38501/how-to-show-https-on-all-pages-of-site)

Comment: Absolutely no answer to my question there. Plese read the question. Not a duplicate of that.

Comment: lol this is exactly the safest option to change https for SEO, make both unsecure and secure link as `https://`  and Auto-redirect to Base URL set to `NO`

Comment: So it will automatically 301 redirect http-version of all pages to https-version of the same pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Magento does automatically do a 301 redirect. But only on and to the homepage. So http://www.example.com is redirected to https://www.example.com. And http://www.example.com/x.html is also redirected to https://www.example.com. So it is advisable to do a .htaccess redirect which takes into consideration the deeper pages of the site.

Furthermore you can check what happens if you try to access your site with and without the www subdomain in relation to http and https. In some cases both are accessible which you do not want because of duplicate content.

**EDIT**: 
Also check your setting for  System > Configuration > General > Web > Url Option > Auto-redirect to Base URL

**BONUS EDIT**:
While you are at it. In most cases the CMS homepage is also accessible trough www.example.com/home. You might want to redirect that page to to avoid another case of duplicate content.

Comment: One web page suggested that you should also do this in .htaccess:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co.uk$

[NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

So there is no need for this?

Comment: Do you mean the 301 redirect? Yes, it might be a good idea do that. In that case you will be absolutely sure your redirects are setup correct. In SEO you don't want to take any chances. Does the page suggest a "why"?

Comment: Not sure. [Here is the page](https://blog.aheadworks.com/2015/10/magento-seo-cases/) Case 1 there.

Comment: I would implement a solution in the .htaccess as suggested. Just to be 100% sure. Like I said you don't want to take any risks with SEO. Besides it doesn't hurt anything or cost much time.

Comment: Should the Auto-redirect to Base URL be set to no or yes?

Comment: It should be set to yes. I also did some tests. Magento only does the correct redirect on the homepage. If you try to land on a deeper page it redirect to the homepage, which you obviously don't want. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to https is usually causes bump of positions in serp.

If you want to minimise the consequences let crawler to index urls with https first and only after it is done place 301 redirect.

You can do for this:

- change canonical tags (place there urls with https);
- change links in your content (it is hard, but do it if possible);
- change links in template.
- update sitemap.